# How to filter an array of random words to an array of hashtags?

Tags: java, lambda

For example, `["ab", "#SomeHash", "qwlerkj", "!@#!@", "sdfs", "#anotherhash"]` to `["#SomeHash", "#anotherhash"]`, or an ArrayList containing `["#SomeHash", "#anotherhash"]`.

I tried using lambda4j, and it keeps giving me an empty list.

```
List<String> hashtagWords = select(statusText.split(" "), hasItemInArray(startsWith("#")));
```

I am using Java 7, so I cannot use Java 8 functionalities.
Please help me.

Comment: Why not to use simple loop? Iterate over all elements, test them with your hash condition, if element will pass test add it to new result list. `List<String> hashtagWords = new ArrayList<>(); for (String s : statusText.split(" ")) { if (s.startsWith("#")) hashtagWords.add(s); }`

Comment: Could also perform a regular expression on the original string.

Comment: @Pshemo I want to do it a fancy way because I need to show this code to people.

Comment: Please define *fancy*. And please put that requirement in your question.

Comment: I wanted to use a concise one liner, but I think I'll just use a loop.

Comment: @user2418202 : improved answer with lamda4j , hope its more concise as you wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly old school, but does the job

```
    List<String> list  = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> hashTagList  = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("ab");
    list.add("#SomeHash");
    list.add("qwlerkj");
    list.add("!@#!@");
    list.add("sdfs");
    list.add("#anotherhash");
    Iterator<String> listItr = list.iterator();
    while (listItr.hasNext()){
        String element =  listItr.next();
        if(element.startsWith("#")){
            hashList.add(element);
        }
    }
```

`hasTagList` contains the hash Strings

**EDIT:**

using [Lambda4j](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lambdaj/) and [Hamcrest Matcher](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/StringStartsWith.html) can be done in single line without iterations.

```
List<String> hashWordsList = filter(startsWith("#"), 
asList("ab","#SomeHash","qwlerkj","!@#!@","sdfs","#anotherhash"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You said in your title you have an array of random words, but your code sample makes it look like you have a `String` (`statusText`). I'm going to assume here you have an array already. (You can use `String.split()` or whatever you need to get it.)

In Java 7 you could do it this way:

```
List<String> hashTagWords = new ArrayList<>();
for (String word : statusWords) {
    if (word.startsWith("#")) {
        hashTagWords.add(word);
    }
}
return hashTagWords;
```

Once you get to Java 8, this should do the trick:

```
return Arrays.stream(statusWords)
    .filter(word -> word.startsWith("#"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```